# Is it only for efficiency, running tests on macOS even if the app will never be deployed to macOS?

Tags: testing

I'm using a MacBook at work. Per company policy, no other devices are allowed. I am developing a Go application, the production environment is Linux and will be Linux only. But I run tests *locally* to determine whether my work is ready to be reviewed because the app, as far as I know, is not using OS-dependent features, so local test results are highly likely to match results from Linux. False-positives will be covered by CI server.

I had never thought about false-negatives, which, luckily, a friend of mine (not a coworker but also a programmer) brought up with, telling his episode:

> I was asked to fix a test that passed on Linux (CI) but failed on macOS, is this right?
> I mean, the app is ultimately going to be running on Linux anyway.
> (He never runs tests locally; always does on remote prod-like environment.)

Is running the test on macOS just a matter of sacrificing a bit of correctness to gain more efficiency?

Answer (score 3):

When determining where and how to run tests, there are two factors to think about:

1. How fast will I get feedback from this test?
2. How reliable will that feedback be?

The ability to run tests locally shortens the feedback look. Finding potential problems before you commit the code and allow others to build on your changes helps to make sure that everyone is building on a more solid, higher quality foundation. Short, fast feedback loops are a good thing.

However, any time there's a difference between the environment where testing is happening and the actual deployment environment, you run a risk of unreliable feedback, which includes both false positives and false negatives. In this particular case, not only is your underlying operating system different, but there may be differences in the compiler, compiler flags and configuration, native libraries, and so on. Each of these differences between the dev (and test) environment and the production environment is the ability to detect an error that won't exist in production (a false positive) or fail to detect an error that will (a false negative).

It's normal for companies to minimize the baseline configurations of computers given to staff. It allows for a more easily managed IT infrastructure when it comes to patches, tool compatibility, and the necessary knowledge of IT support staff. I don't consider it realistic to expect developers to have development machines that exactly match the production environment for everything they build.

Fortunately, there are solutions. Virtual machines and containers can allow developers to build an environment that is much closer to their production environment and still have a good developer experience. You can still have the fast feedback loops of local development and test while minimizing the number of differences that delay the discovery of problems. It's not an either/or choice in this case.

Comment: Let me sum up your thought: The key is finding a good balance between two factors, how fast and how reliable. Local virtual machines and containers could provide a better balance than local native runtime.

Comment: For my case, I currently don't know what factors the local runtime (macOS) may affect integrity of testing. To actually find the best option, I have to evaluate each one (empirically if feasible).

Comment: @Jinux I think it's less about finding a balance. We have very good ways of ensuring consistent environments. For the majority of cases, it is possible to build a VM or container that duplicates the production environment with respect to the runtime environment. You could take it a step further and use VMs and containers to simulate nodes in a network. The first question is if some kind of virtualization or containerization is feasible. If it is, how closely does it need to mirror the production environment and how do you get it available for the team.

Comment: I get your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that:

- A positive result - means the test detected a bug (using the medical definition where a positive result indicates an illness has been detected).
- The the full test suite that runs locally (on the Mac) runs on the CI server.
- The CI service is strictly more accurate (both positive and negative) than the Mac test - meaning that it is never the case that the Mac test is accurate and the CI test is false.

We end up with the following situations:

| # | Bug Exists | Local Status | CI Status | Issue? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Positive | True Positive | False Negative | Violates Assumption |
| 2 | Negative | True Negative | False Positive | Violates Assumption |
| 3 | Positive | True Positive | True Positive | Fix your code/bug |
| 4 | Negative | True Negative | True Negative | All good - No issue |
| 5 | Positive | False Negative | False Negative | Add additional test |
| 6 | Negative | False Positive | False Positive | Fix your tests |
| 7 | Positive | False Negative | True Positive | *See below* |
| 8 | Negative | False Positive | True Negative | *See below* |

Edit: Per the comments here is the same table (in the same order) with different language:

| # | Bug Exists | Local Test Failed | CI Test Failed | Issue? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Yes | No | Violates Assumption |
| 2 | No | No | Yes | Violates Assumption |
| 3 | Yes | Yes | Yes | Fix your code/bug |
| 4 | No | No | No | All good - No issue |
| 5 | Yes | No | No | Add additional test |
| 6 | No | Yes | Yes | Fix your tests |
| 7 | Yes | No | Yes | *See below* |
| 8 | No | Yes | No | *See below* |

Cases #1 and #2 violate the assumption that the CI server is more accurate than the Mac tests - This shouldn't occur, if it does you will need to dig into it.

Case #3 - saves time since your local tests indicates that you need to fix a bug before submitting to the CI server.

Case #4 - is a valid test pass - no issue.

Case #5 and #6 - means you have a problem with your test and you need to fix it - again you get local/early notification of the problem which is a good thing.

Case #7 - Your local test didn't catch a bug, but the CI server did.

Firstly you should see if you can modify the test, so that both the CI and local servers detect the problem.
If this isn't possible create a "Linux Only" test group that runs before the other tests on the CI server - that way developers can have a high degree of confidence once they see that group has passed on the CI server (assuming they ran the full suite locally). It also means they get this feedback sooner - rather than having to wait for all the other tests to run first.

Consider not running it locally on the Mac if its going to give an incorrect result, since it will be more confusing to developers "works on my machine" syndrome.

Case #8 - Your local test is failing (incorrectly), but the CI server isn't.

These situations degrade your developers faith in the local test suite (such they may stop running it). The corrective actions are the same as case #7 - however the priority of fixing is much higher - the test must be immediately excluded from running on the Mac (and prioritized on the CI server) so that additional developers don't get impacted by it.

**Summary**

Case #7 is not really a big problem - fix it when you can.

Case #8 is the one you need to be concerned about / deal with immediately.

In all other cases you just gain efficiency by being able to run the tests locally - instead of having to wait for the CI server to run the tests.

Comment: It was intentional to stay with the OP's original False Positive language, 

For example, so that one can say that case 7 is a: Local False Positive

and case 8 is a Local False Negative.

Comment: I'm having difficulty interpreting those columns and their values. Would you mind if you elaborate?

EDIT: Does "Positive / True / False" mean "Bug actually exists. Local test detects. CI test fails to detect."?

Answer (score 1):

There are bugs that can make test fails in rather unpredictable ways. They fail in environment A, but not in environment B. But unless you know exactly why that is, you would have to assume that the real application fails in the hands of a customer with an environment similar to B.

So in this situation: You need to find out what’s going on, and fix it unless you can prove it’s harmless. Even then you want to fix it because failing tests are a pain.